# UILineBreakModeTailTruncation in sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: is ignored

Tags: iphone, height, uilabel

I'm using `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` to calculate the actual height of a `UILabel`.

However, the height I get is always based on the complete `NSString` (before it gets truncated).

In fact, both `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` and `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` produce identical results as if the `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation` gets ignored !

This code produces `60.000000` no matter what I try, but the first result should be less than 60. Any idea why ?

```
CGSize aSize;

aSize=[@"One two three four five six seven eight nine ten" sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];

NSLog(@"aSize.height: %f",aSize.height); //returns 60.000000

aSize=[@"One two three four five six seven eight nine ten" sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];

NSLog(@"aSize.height: %f",aSize.height); //returns 60.000000
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found out that the string did not get truncated because the frame can contain the entire string.

Comment: You should tag your own answer as the accepted answer, so that the question comes up as answered in the database.